# Closing bootstrap modal with setInterval causes repeated closures

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, setinterval

I have a modal box (a bootstrap modal). After the user has made a particular ajax request and the 'okay' comes back from the server I have it set to close the dialog after 1.5 seconds.

`setInterval(function(){
                $('#modalname').modal('hide');
},1500);`

This works okay the first time but thereafter each time I open the modal via a click of a button it keeps closing it automatically. If I remove the setInterval then it's fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) instead, as you need to execute it onetime, `setInterval()` will call the function after every interval of specified time, while `setTimeout()` only calls once:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 

           $('#modalname').modal('hide'); 

          },1500);
```

Answer (score 4):

**[`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval)** executes a function infinite amout of times every `n` milliseconds.
You should use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('#modalname').modal('hide');
},1500);
```